# Ubuntu Shortcuts for Ubuntu 14 — Beginning and end of line

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

**OSX**
Control-A Move to the beginning of the line or paragraph.
Control-E Move to the end of a line or paragraph.

Whats the equivalent for system wide shortcut on Ubnuntu 14? Where do I set those?

Comment: In what application? If it's the shell you're talking about, then if you're running the same shell on Ubuntu with the same settings, then it would be the same shortcuts.

Comment: I want a system wide shortcut. In OSX I can use that shortcut on command line, sublime, form fields...

Answer (score 4):

On my Dell I can use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key for this purpose. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>. It also works in terminal so I don't have to remember what app I'm in!

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 by the way.

Comment: I'm using a MagicKeyboard 2. This worked for me on Ubuntu 20. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Ummm, would you believe Home, End.

It may depend on the application, but in most I use Home for begining of line, Ctrl+Home for beginning of page, End for end of line, Ctrl+End of end of page.

I use these keys in the bash shell all the time (Within  X-Windows, on the Console, and from putty via ssh)

Now this does depend on having the correct terminal (TERM environment variable) set.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm transitioning from macOS to Ubuntu and boy do I miss command-left, command-right, command-shift-left, and command-shift-right (respectively: jump to beginning of line, end of line, beginning of line expanding selection, end of line expanding selection). It seems to be at the OS level in macOS and works for every application.